# Images Not Loading in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to display images in my Symfony application as follows:

```
<img src="{{ asset('../assets/img/test.png') }}" alt="test" class="center-block" />
```

I am getting an empty placeholder, as if the image asset does not exist.

When I try and load that image, it downloads, but cannot be opened, saying "corrupt image" or similar. However, when opening the downloaded file in a text editor, I am seeing at the start of the file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 226415
```

And thereafter, the remainder of the file. If I strip out the above code block from the file and save it, the file opens just fine.

The HTTP response headers are being passed back into the file, and I am not sure why this is.

**How can I get the image to render properly?**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `asset` just generate the path to the image, nothing more. is it correct?

Comment: Downloading the file was my way of proving that the file path was OK. It is getting prefixed with the HTTP response headers, and preventing the file from opening!

Comment: so, the path is correct, but the image isn't displayed? seems to me that the image itself is corrupted

Comment: Image is definitely not corrupt. Symfony almost appears to be serving these files via it's router and adding that response in, breaking all images!

Comment: got it; are you using apache? `mod_rewrite` is enabled?

Comment: Thanks @Federico - Yes, apache via XAMPP, mod_rewrite enabled via .htaccess file (the file is supplied during first setup of Symfony)

Comment: Can we see your routes configuration?

Comment: Very simple at the moment!
`homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: VendorMyBundle:Home:index }

guides_home:
    path:     /guides
    defaults: { _controller: VendorMyBundle:guides:index }`